# NPM sonarqube-scanner fails with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: npm, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We use the npm package sonarqube-scanner version 2.1.1 to analyze our angular/typescript project. But starting yesterday the sonarqube analysis failed with a 401 while downloading the the sonar-scanner from the website.

I checked the url and https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0.1227-linux.zip does indeed need authentication. Does anyone know why or is there a workaround?

```
09-Oct-2018 13:24:08    [11:24:08] Starting SonarQube analysis...
09-Oct-2018 13:24:08    [11:24:08] Checking if executable exists: /root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/bin/sonar-scanner
09-Oct-2018 13:24:08    [11:24:08] Could not find executable in "/root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner".
09-Oct-2018 13:24:08    [11:24:08] Proceed with download of the platform binaries for SonarQube Scanner...
09-Oct-2018 13:24:08    [11:24:08] Creating /root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner
09-Oct-2018 13:24:08    [11:24:08] Downloading from https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0.1227-linux.zip
09-Oct-2018 13:24:08    [11:24:08] (executable will be saved in cache folder: /root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner)
09-Oct-2018 13:24:09    [11:24:09] ERROR: impossible to download and extract binary: Response code 401 (Unauthorized)
09-Oct-2018 13:24:09    [11:24:09]        SonarQube Scanner binaries probably don't exist for your OS (linux).
09-Oct-2018 13:24:09    [11:24:09]        In such situation, the best solution is to install the standard SonarQube Scanner (requires a JVM).
09-Oct-2018 13:24:09    [11:24:09]        Check it out at https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner.html
09-Oct-2018 13:24:09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they changed their url for the binary download. If your using the npm package you need to install 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I hit this today.  After investigating, it looks like sonar moved their binaries from "sonarsource.bintray.com" to "binaries.sonarsource.com".  The rest of the url structure looks the same.

Here's the sonar page that links to the downloads:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner